# Does the structure of "UNB" and "UNH" segments differs over different EDIFACT versions?

Tags: edi, edifact

does any one know whether the structure of "UNB" and "UNH" differs between different EDIFACT versions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it does change....but not much.
actually, it is not tied to a directory, but a syntax version.
eg: UNB+UNOA:2+
this value '2' here indicates syntax version 2.
different syntax version can have different UNB/UNH.
And indeed, for syntax version 4 quite some fields have been added.

Answer (score 0):

you lokk the services segments on the CEFACT official site or UN/CEFACT.
The structure segment has different during the Dictionnary version D96A, D01B, ... 
The services segment was change in version 400100 about UNB UNH the warring about the structure data also... in UNB the date Interchange change YYMMDD change into YYYYMMDD !